# distinguishing between facilitate, possibility , and no way

Tags: vocabulary

Now, would you please show me the concept or the ***subtle*** **difference** between these, ***semantically***?

Higher education is not possible

There is no way to study higher education

Higher education is not facilitated.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, these sentences don't have "subtle differences": they're completely different.

Initial point: "Higher education" normally means "education after high school, i.e. college or university". In context it might mean education beyond some other specific level. But let's assume for our purposes here that it means college.

"Higher education is not possible." Depending on context, that might mean: (a) The particular person or group we are discussing cannot under any circumstances be admitted to college, or could not succeed there. Or, (b) No education beyond high school has any meaning or value.

"There is no way to study higher education." The subject of higher education itself cannot be studied. This isn't saying that you can't go to college, but that no one can analyze what goes on in college.

"Higher education is not facilitated." We will not assist you in going to college. Or depending on context, perhaps no one will assist you in going to college. This doesn't mean that you can't go to college, just that you are not going to get help from someone else.